# remove link from Linux namespace

Tags: linux, namespace, network-namespaces

I created a namespace in Linux with 'ip netns add foo', created a pair of veth interfaces and moved one in the namespace. I set up IP addresses etc., so that now I can ping my 'foo' namespace from the default namespace, i.e. a host.

However the problem is with *removing* a link from the namespace foo back to the default one. Which command(s) should I use?

Comment: I believe it is answered here: http://serverfault.com/a/704717/191811

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From within namespace foo:

```
ip link set <veth-name> netns 1
```

From the global namespace:

```
ip netns exec foo ip link set <veth-name> netns 1
```

It moves the interface back to the global namespace.

Pitfall: avoid having the namespace named "1".

Yes, you can. You can create namespace "1". But during namespace "1" existence there is no way to move an interface from a namespace to the global namespace with the proposed method. All moves are performed to namespace "1" instead. So avoid having namespace "1".

Answer (score 4):

```
ip netns pids foo | xargs kill
ip netns del foo
```